# sending requests for a updating webpage in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I want to send a request for extracting data from a website. 
I am writing the following code:

```
import requests as req
from requests import Request, Session
from requests import post, get

resp = post(
"https://www.somewebsite.net/ext/data/",
{"from": "25.08.2017", "to": "25.08.2017", "download": "true", "_download": "on", "tsoId": "1", "dataType": "AAA"},
stream=True )
```

every 2 minutes, the website get updated and I want to send same request every 3 minutes to get the new inputs. Can I do it only using requests library or I have to use Selenium and BS ?

Comment: There's no general answer for this. It depends entirely on the website in question. If you can post json data to the website, presumably you could get json back. Which means you only need requests.

Comment: I tried to run the code every 10 seconds to get the data but it didn't work !

Comment: If you want help figuring out why your code "didn't work", you need to provide a [mcve]. We have no idea what the problem might be, since we know nothing about the web site you are trying to work with, or what response or results your code had.